# Google email account block for the security reason

Tags: email

I've configured google account to send the email from my application.

This works well with my application. But When test the application, this will work well for 10 or 20 emails. But after sometime, it blocks the application to send the email for the security reasons.

After that, I need to login again and should authorize the application to send the email that to verify "I am not a robo".

Here my need is, I need to send the email without any interruption from my email through application.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) helps. There you can change the settings of your google account to trust unsecure apps.

Comment: Yes, this allow the application to send email. But after sometime again it blocks. google assumes the system as robot and when manually login, it ask for the verification. Since this procedure is enabled, then from my application, the email is not dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is said here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/43692?hl=en

A third party software logging automatically in to your account will trigger the account blocking process.

Comment: Yes. It's automatically blocking that. I need to run my application without interruption. Is there anyway to implement this? Or do I need to have separate email domain for this one?

Comment: You can try to change the connection settings https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Or this link, which seems interesting for your case
http://www.ghacks.net/2014/07/21/gmail-starts-block-less-secure-apps-enable-access/